# How to merge multiple MODIS swaths into one plot in python?

Tags: python, hdf, satellite-image

I want to mosaic/merge multiple swaths of the MODIS dataset (MOD06_L2) using python. I used the example (http://hdfeos.org/zoo/MORE/LAADS/MOD/MOD04_L2_merge.py) to read multiple files and merge. But I am getting an error while doing so, how to correct this error?

I would like to know is there any better way than this, to merge/mosaic MODIS HDF files into one?

```
import os
import glob                                                                 
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

# The first file in 3 swath files.
FILE_NAME = 'MOD06_L2.A2017126.0655.061.2019226193408.hdf'
GEO_FILE_NAME ='MOD06_L2.A2017126.0655.061.2019226193408.hdf'
DATAFIELD_NAME = 'Brightness_Temperature'

from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

i = 0

for file in list(glob.glob('MOD06*.hdf')):
    reader = open(file)
    hdf = SD(file, SDC.READ)
    # Read dataset.
    data2D = hdf.select(DATAFIELD_NAME)
    data = data2D[:,:].astype(np.double)
    hdf_geo = SD(GEO_FILE_NAME, SDC.READ)
    # Read geolocation dataset.
    lat = hdf_geo.select('Latitude')
    latitude = lat[:,:]
    lon = hdf_geo.select('Longitude')
    longitude = lon[:,:]
    # Retrieve attributes.
    attrs = data2D.attributes(full=1)
    lna=attrs["long_name"]
    long_name = lna[0]
    aoa=attrs["add_offset"]
    add_offset = aoa[0]
    fva=attrs["_FillValue"]
    _FillValue = fva[0]
    sfa=attrs["scale_factor"]
    scale_factor = sfa[0]
    vra=attrs["valid_range"]
    valid_min = vra[0][0]
    valid_max = vra[0][1]        
    ua=attrs["units"]
    units = ua[0]
    invalid = np.logical_or(data > valid_max,data < valid_min)
    invalid = np.logical_or(invalid, data == _FillValue)
    data[invalid] = np.nan
    data = (data - add_offset) * scale_factor 
    datam = np.ma.masked_array(data, np.isnan(data))
    if i == 0 :
        data_m = datam
        latitude_m = latitude
        longitude_m = longitude
    else:
        data_m = np.vstack([data_m, datam])
        latitude_m = np.vstack([latitude_m, latitude])
        longitude_m = np.vstack([longitude_m, longitude])
    i = i + 1
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
                llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat=90,
                llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 91, 45))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180, 45), labels=[True,False,False,True])
sc = m.scatter(longitude_m, latitude_m, c=data_m, s=0.1, cmap=plt.cm.jet,
               edgecolors=None, linewidth=0)
cb = m.colorbar()
cb.set_label(units)


# Put title using the first file.
basename = os.path.basename(FILE_NAME)
plt.title('{0}\n{1}'.format(basename, DATAFIELD_NAME))
fig = plt.gcf()

# Save image.
pngfile = "{0}.py.png".format(basename)
fig.savefig(pngfile)
```

It showing an error

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 4604040 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 657720.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the full error message so it is clear which line it occurs on. For the moment, the ratio between the two numbers is exactly 7, so some parameter is 7 times larger or smaller than expected. Does your data maybe have 7 spectral channels and you have accidentally passed 7 channels instead of 1?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but i searched for the exact error and got this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552320/scatter-problem-valueerror-c-argument-has-2-elements-which-is-inconsistent)

Comment: Might [tag:satpy] help you at all?